# How can I embed Photos from my Google Photos onto a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-photos

I want to add some photos I took with my phone camera to a Google Map I am working on. There are 4 options when editing a marker for adding content.

- Google Image Search
- URL
- Video Search
- Youtube URL

When I try to use the share link from the photo in my Google Photos I get the following error message: *We can't find the image at that URL*.
I've tried posting the photo on Google+ and sharing that link and I get the same error. There is no option for uploading an image from your local drive.

I would think something like this should be pretty basic. Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shareable link that you get from Google Photos cannot be used in many applications, it doesn't just show the picture, it also puts it in a display showing the date (and any other pictures that you have included in the same shareable link)

Instead, you need to:

- In [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/), click into the picture you want to use, so it is the only one on the screen
- Right click, and choose **Copy Image URL**  (that's the option in Chrome,
  other browsers have slightly different words for the same action)
- Paste that Image URL  (not the shareable link) into the Image-URL
  field in Maps.